# Drag and drop is not working on ag-grid-angular

Tags: angular, drag-and-drop, ag-grid

I am using ag grid angular in pivot mode. The problem I am facing is unable to drag and drop columns in Row, value and column areads. I can add columns in these areas from ts file but not from UI with drag and drop. I can take out any column from these areas but not add and column. Here is ag code.

```
<ag-grid-angular #agGrid
                 style="width: 90%; height: 500px; margin-top: 30px;"
                 id="myGrid"
                 [rowData]="rowData"
                 class="ag-theme-balham"
                 [columnDefs]="columnDefs"
                 [enableColResize]="true"
                 [enableSorting]="true"
                 [sideBar]="sideBar"
                 [defaultColDef]="defaultColDef"
                 [pivotMode]="true"
                 [statusBar]="statusBar"
                 [enableRangeSelection]="true"
                 enableRowGroup="true"
                 dragAndDrop =" true"
                 [animateRows]="true"
                 (gridReady)="onGridReady($event)"></ag-grid-angular>
```

Anyone can tell me what I am missing here.

Plunker like for similar issue: https://plnkr.co/edit/xtPbAztpG14bleAF9bgy?p=preview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In ag-grid mode you can not drag and drop the row. However you can make row draggable by adding draggable=true dynamically on mouseover (mouseover) get the cell id through dom and make it draggable.

```
A simple code would be

    // This method is used to handle the drag row functionality in ag-grid. It adds the draggable event to rows in grid.
    this.gridOptions.onCellMouseOver = (dragEvent: any) => {
      if (dragEvent.event.target && dragEvent.event.target.offsetParent.classList.contains('ag-row')) {
        dragEvent.event.target.offsetParent.setAttribute("pdraggable", "data");
        dragEvent.event.target.offsetParent.setAttribute("draggable", "true");
        //dragStart event needs to be added as firefox is not reading draggable=true without this.
        //https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/214613/draggable-true-is-not-working-in-firefox-for-lightning-component
        dragEvent.event.target.offsetParent.addEventListener('dragstart', (event: any) => {
          event.dataTransfer.setData('data', 'data');
        }, true);
        this.draggedRow = dragEvent.data;
      }
      this.draggedRow = dragEvent.data;
    };
  }
```

Comment: Hi Aman... you solution is working perfectly fine. But I got another way with no manual code. Ag-grid inbuild provide this function...
https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-side-bar/

Comment: @Abhash786 how have you achieved drag and drop functionality from sidebar?

Answer (score 0):

This answer is for all who are facing same issue...
Ag-grid inbuild provide this functionality
please refer below...

https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-side-bar/